# ListView без id

Tags: java, android, xml

В чем может быть ошибка?

```
Error:(13, 69) Gradle: error: cannot find symbol variable listView
private ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

listView присутствует в активити:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp" android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textChooseTypePlan" android:layout_height="50dp"/>
```

Захожу в R , а там отсутствует данный id.

Comment: `import android.R` есть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пересоберите проект, вкладка `Build`, в ней сначала нажмите `Clean Project`, дождитесь окончания, потом нажмите `Rebuild Project`:)

А вообще если приглядеться к этой строчке:

```
private ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Вы пытаетесь проинициализировать поле класса через поиск `View` в контенте `Activity`, которого еще нету. Более того, на тот момент еще нет экземпляра класса самой `Activity`.

Вам надо инициализировать переменную `ListView listView` внутри методов жизненного цикла `Activity`, если действие происходит в `Activity`, после того, как Вы зададите ему контент, например так:

```
private ListView mListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(/*Id*/);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
}
```

Comment: Не помогает, заглянул в файл R, а там не добавлен данный id. Возможно отключилось автодобавление? Можно его восстановить? (Intellij IDEA)

Comment: И еще странная особенность, в среде оно подсвечивается, как-будто его видит, то есть в коде ошибку не покаывает,а лишь при создании уже apk.

Comment: Обновил ответ :)